# TYPO3 v9.5.8 - 404 errorHandling works only on second level - How to fix it?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a really strange behaviour in my TYPO3 CMS v9.5.8
Inside the site settings i configured the errorHandler for 404 pages as follows

```
rootPageId: 1
base: 'http://www.example.com/'
[...]
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=97'
```

when i now try to open `http://www.example.com/foo` (which does not exist) the Site shows me the root page (id:1, same as `example.com`).

BUT if I access `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` or `http://www.example.com/foo/baz` or any other non-existent second level site - then I see the configured 404 site (id:97).

What could go wrong here? How can get the "normal" 404 behaviour?

EDIT: I figured out, that `foo` can be both. Existent and non existent. The important thing is: before the non existent subsite (lvl 3, 4, 5, 6, ...), there has to be a domain (lvl 1) and at least a lvl 2 subpage.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Find a (currently work-in-progress) fix for your scenario at https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/61346

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your reply. I applied the Changes but sadly that didn't resolve my problem. I missed to mention, that in my example the `foo` and `bar` parts are no language subpaths. I also edited the Question as i found out that `foo` can be a existent or non existent subpage.